# Creating a custom role which cannot delete a resource group or individual resources within the resource group

Tags: azure, permissions, azure-resource-manager, azure-rbac

I want to create a custom role for developers.

[image]

With this custom role the developers should have contributor access to the resource group "TestRessourceGroup" and all its stored resources but the developers should not have the permission to delete this resource group or individual resources within the resource group.

This is what I have so far:

```
{
       "properties": {
        "roleName": "Contributor without permission to delete resources",
        "description": "Grants full access to manage all resources, but does not allow you to assign roles in Azure RBAC, manage assignments in Azure Blueprints, share image galleries, or delete resources.",
        "assignableScopes": [
            "/"
        ],
        "permissions": [
            {
                "actions": [
                    "*"
                ],
                "notActions": [
                    "Microsoft.Authorization/*/Delete",
                    "Microsoft.Authorization/*/Write",
                    "Microsoft.Authorization/elevateAccess/Action",
                    "Microsoft.Blueprint/blueprintAssignments/write",
                    "Microsoft.Blueprint/blueprintAssignments/delete",
                    "Microsoft.Compute/galleries/share/action",
                    "Microsoft.Resources/subscriptions/resourceGroups/delete"
                ],
                "dataActions": [],
                "notDataActions": []
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

The developers should still be able to:

- delete blobs and containers within a Storage Account
- delete compute instances or compute clusters within AMLS

What do I need to add so that users with this custom role cannot delete a resource group or individual resources (like Storage Accounts, Databricks, Key Vaults, AMLS .....) within the resource group but **anything else** is working like with the *normal* contributor access?

Comment: something like `*/delete` in the `notActions` should work ?

Answer (score 1):

In you don't want to include resource deletion, the easiest way is to add `*/delete` in the the `notActions` array:

```json
{
  "properties": {
    "roleName": "Contributor without permission to delete resources",
    "description": "Grants full access to manage all resources, but does not allow you to assign roles in Azure RBAC, manage assignments in Azure Blueprints, share image galleries, or delete resources.",
    "assignableScopes": [
      "/"
    ],
    "permissions": [
      {
        "actions": [
          "*"
        ],
        "notActions": [
          "*/delete",
          "Microsoft.Authorization/*/Write",
          "Microsoft.Authorization/elevateAccess/Action",
          "Microsoft.Blueprint/blueprintAssignments/write",
          "Microsoft.Compute/galleries/share/action"
        ],
        "dataActions": [],
        "notDataActions": []
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

You could then having another role to allow users to delete resources inside Machine learning workspace:

```json
{
  "properties": {
    "roleName": "Allow ML workspace resources deletion",
    "description": "",
    "assignableScopes": [
      "/"
    ],
    "permissions": [
      {
        "actions": [
          "Microsoft.MachineLearningServices/workspaces/*/delete"
        ],
        "notActions": [],
        "dataActions": [],
        "notDataActions": []
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

If you create an AAD group and assign these two roles to the group, it should work.

Comment: no, I do not think that this will solve the issue because this will interfere with "Microsoft.MachineLearningServices/workspaces/*/delete" and "Microsoft.MachineLearningServices/workspaces/computes/*/delete"

Comment: you said you dont want people to delete anything ? should they be able to delete some resources ?

Comment: they should not be able to delete Azure resources, like AMLS, Storage Account, Databricks, Key Vault ....., but they should be able to delete computes, and clusters within AMLS.

Comment: could you please edit your answer with the additional information ?

Comment: you are right! I will do this!

Comment: Also have you check the `AzureML Data Scientist` builtin role: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles#azureml-data-scientist ?

Comment: we did but we decided that we need contributor access without the permission to delete a resource group or individual resources (like Storage Accounts, Databricks, Key Vaults, AMLS .....) within the resource group.

Comment: @Daniel let me know if my new answer make sense for you

Comment: sry, it does not